# Curvature of multivariate polynomial at the origin

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, multivariate-polynomial

For any Gaussian curvature $K$, the polynomial $x^2 + \frac{K}{2}y^2$ has Gaussian curvature of K at the origin.  Let $M$ be a Riemann Manifold of dimension $n$ and let $x$ be a point in $M$.  Does there exist a polynomial $P$ such that the local geometry at the origin of $P$ is isometric to the local geometry of $x$?

Comment: You mean the Gaussian curvature of the *graph*. For higher dimensions, curvature is a very complicated object, not just a number. But to even locally isometrically embed a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n>2$ typically requires very high dimensions, so you're not going to end up with a graph of a real-valued function at all.

Comment: When I hear that the Riemann Curvature Tensor for an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ has $\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}$ free variables, I take this to mean that we could identify the local geometry of any point $p$ in $M$ with some subset of Euclidean space of dimension $\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}$ in a one-to-one matter.  Is there some truth to this idea?